# Converting analog values to PPM: MQ135 and MQ131

Tags: sensor, adc, gas-sensor

I am making an air quality monitoring system that makes use of an ESP8266 and an analog extender [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1115). The main problem is that I get analog values and don't know how to convert them to PPM without using its sensor library. [MQ135](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/Gas/SNS-MQ135/resources/SNS-MQ135.pdf)  [MQ131](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/9/9/6/e/4/mq131-datasheet-low.pdf)

```
#include "ADS1X15.h"
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 14
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

ADS1115 ADS(0x48); 
               
// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);                

float Temperature;
float Humidity;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(__FILE__);
  Serial.print("ADS1X15_LIB_VERSION: ");
  Serial.println(ADS1X15_LIB_VERSION);

  ADS.begin();

  pinMode(DHTPIN, INPUT);

  dht.begin(); 
}

void loop() 
{
  ADS.setGain(0);

  int16_t val_0 = ADS.readADC(0);  
  int16_t val_1 = ADS.readADC(1);  
  int16_t val_2 = ADS.readADC(2);  
  int16_t val_3 = ADS.readADC(3); 
  Temperature = dht.readTemperature(); // Gets the values of the temperature
  Humidity = dht.readHumidity(); // Gets the values of the humidity  

  float f = ADS.toVoltage(1);  // voltage factor

  Serial.print("\tMQ135: "); Serial.println(val_0);
  Serial.print("\tMQ131: "); Serial.println(val_1);
  Serial.print("\tTemperature: "); Serial.println(Temperature);
  Serial.print("\tHumidity: "); Serial.println(Humidity);
  // Serial.print("\tAnalog1: "); Serial.print(val_1); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.println(val_1 * f, 3);
  // Serial.print("\tAnalog2: "); Serial.print(val_2); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.println(val_2 * f, 3);
  // Serial.print("\tAnalog3: "); Serial.print(val_3); Serial.print('\t'); Serial.println(val_3 * f, 3);
  Serial.println();

  delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each sensor has its own calibration curves.
Note that heater resistance is low: 34 +/- 3 Ohm -> current is ...
[MQ131 and Arduino](https://github.com/ostaquet/Arduino-MQ131-driver)
Values of Rsensor translate to ppm (blue curve).
It is a "bit" difficult because of the different gazes that can be detected simultaneously.

The detector is a simple attenuator Rsensor-RL.
[Calibrate](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fostaquet%2FArduino-MQ131-driver%2Fmaster%2Fextras%2Fdatasheet%2FSensitivity_curves.xlsx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK) in "pure" air.
One measures voltage across RL and then calculate Rsensor.
If \$ Vload= F . Vsupply \$
then,     \$ Rsensor = RLoad . F/(1-F) \$.

You have then to interpolate on the curve (exponential function, blue curve for that sensor).

[image]

[image]